# Web sockets not connecting in Next.js app deployed on Netlify with custom server

Tags: javascript, websocket, next.js, socket.io, netlify

I am trying to deploy a Next.js app on Netlify with a custom server that uses web sockets for real-time updates. However, when I deploy the app on Netlify, the web sockets are not connecting, but they are working in development. I have tried different configurations and troubleshooting methods, but I am still unable to get the web sockets to work on Netlify. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this problem? Thank you in advance for your help.

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import io from 'socket.io-client';

// Custom hook to handle socket connection
const useSocket = (onConnect, onOrderUpdate, onProductUpdate) => {
    // useEffect hook to handle socket connection
    useEffect(() => {
        // create new socket connection
        const socket = io()

        // if onConnect function is passed as an argument, register it as a listener for the "connect" event
        if (onConnect) {
            socket.on("connect", onConnect);
        }
        // if onOrderUpdate function is passed as an argument, register it as a listener for the "order-update" event
        if (onOrderUpdate) {
            socket.on("order-update", onOrderUpdate);
        }
        // if onProductUpdate function is passed as an argument, register it as a listener for the "product-update" event
        if (onProductUpdate) {
            socket.on("product-update", onProductUpdate);
        }
        // return a cleanup function to disconnect the socket when the component using the hook unmounts
        // socket disconnet onUnmount if exists
        if (socket) return () => socket.disconnect();
    }, []);
};

export default useSocket;
```

```js
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Order = require('./models/Order.js');
const Product = require('./models/Product.js');
const cookie = require('cookie');
var cors = require('cors');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const exp = express()
    exp.use(cors({
        origin: 'https://pizza-app3.netlify.app'
    }))
    exp.use(bodyParser.json())
    exp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    exp.use((req, res, next) => {
        req.cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie || '');
        next();
    });

    exp.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://pizza-app3.netlify.app");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });


    const server = createServer(exp);
    const io = require('socket.io')(server);

    exp.all('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res);
    });

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('A user connected');

        // Watch for changes in the Order model and emit an 'order-update' event
        Order.watch().on('change', (data) => {
            socket.emit('order-update', data);
        })

        // Watch for changes in the Product model and emit a 'product-update' event
        Product.watch().on('change', (data) => {
            socket.emit('product-update', data);
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('A user disconnected');
        });
    });

    server.listen(PORT, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

```js
{
  "name": "food-website2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "axios": "^1.2.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "cookie": "^0.5.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint": "8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.4",
    "next": "13.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^5.3.4",
    "react-paystack": "^4.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
    "socket.io": "^3.1.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting on the client side? Any messages received in logging on the server side?